# Как получить значение атрибута css?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var attr-1 = $('#slider-img-sl1').attr('display');
```

Нужно проверить скрытый он или нет. И потом записать туда другое значение.

Comment: скрытый это `visibility: hidden` или `display: none` или  какой?

Comment: display: none..

Comment: Нет такого атрибута. Это значение стиля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('#slider-img-sl1').css('display') == 'none') {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если из none сделать block и наоборот, то лучше так

```
$('#slider-img-sl1').toggle();
```

Comment: В старину делали так: `if( $('#slider-img-sl1').css('display') === 'none' ) $('#slider-img-sl1').show() else $('#slider-img-sl1').hide();` :)